# How to extract only the number 1780 in the sample code below

Tags: javascript, html, vba, web-scraping

I am currently trying to get the number 1780 in the code below:

```
<span style="font-size: smaller;" data-bind="text: ' (' + filtered() + ' 
retrieved)', visible: filterVisible()"> (1780 retrieved)</span>
```

I will be running a macro (VBA) that will only download the files from this site if the number of items retrieved is less than 2000. This number can change depending on the input values from excel so I believe I have to use a wildcard for this. For now, how do you get only the number 1780?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming running from vba you can use a css attribute = value selector with contains operator then use split and replace on node's `innerText`. I might also be tempted instead to using regex to extract the number.

```
Dim s As String, arr() As String, num As Long

s = ie.document.querySelector("span[data-bind*='retrieved']").innerText
arr = Split(s, Chr$(32))
num = Replace$(arr(0), "(", vbNullString)
```

Comment: Thank you both so much for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Just grab the content of the element, and replace all non-numbers with nothing.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('span').textContent.replace(/\D/g, ''));
```

```html
<span style="font-size: smaller;" data-bind="text: ' (' + filtered() + ' 
retrieved)', visible: filterVisible()"> (1780 retrieved)</span>
```

If you want to utilize a full expression, you can define a matching group for any sequence of digits after the initial parenthesis, but before the "retrieved" text.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('span').textContent.match(/\((\d+) retrieved\)/)[1]);
```

```html
<span style="font-size: smaller;" data-bind="text: ' (' + filtered() + ' 
retrieved)', visible: filterVisible()"> (1780 retrieved)</span>
```